# CentOs Unable to load pages that are on server

Tags: centos, webserver, web

I am having a little difficulty accessing pages that are on my server.

Under /var/www/html/ I have an index.html page, and when I try to access it from chrome, it times out.

The permissions on html/ are drwxr-xr-x and I am able to ping the IP just fine.

Do any of you have any suggestions on what could be the possible culprit here?

Comment: found the answer, but i'm unable to submit for another 8 hours... run the following commands:

service iptables stop;

chkconfig iptables off;

service httpd restart;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enable access of port 80 with iptables, why would you disable that service ?

`# iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT && service iptables save`